# Why could Drush not find the alias @local?

Tags: 8, drush

I am usin Drupal 8 and Drush 8. I have ~/.drush/local.aliases.drushrc.php. That is the only alias under ~/.drush

Inside local.aliases.drushrc.php, I have

```
$aliases['local'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/html/test/testme/amber/amber_school_dev',
  'uri' => 'http://amber_school_dev.local',
);
```

Run this `drush @local status --debug`

```
Using the Drush script found at /home/kenpeter/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.launcher using pcntl_exec
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.8-commandfiles-0-88373346a2ca94c0c49a48b75b15bd40 [0.02 sec, 3.23 MB]                                                [debug]
$aliases['local'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/html/test/testme/amber/amber_school_dev',
  'uri' => 'http://amber_school_dev.local',
);

$aliases['local'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/html/test/testme/amber/amber_school_dev',
  'uri' => 'http://amber_school_dev.local',
);

$aliases['local'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/html/test/testme/amber/amber_school_dev',
  'uri' => 'http://amber_school_dev.local',
);

Could not find the alias @local [0.06 sec, 6.05 MB]                                                                                 [error]
Undefined index: command notify.drush.inc:60 [0.06 sec, 6.06 MB]                                                                       [notice]
Undefined index: command notify.drush.inc:60 [0.06 sec, 6.06 MB]                                                                       [notice]
```

`drush sa` in site root gives me

```
@none
@self
default
```

Comment: did you also clear the drush cache `druch cc drush`? Additionally you can run `drush status` to see if it found your alias file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `<?php` at the beginning of your aliases file. That's why the contents of your file are printing out when Drush tries to load them.

Answer (score 1):

The aliases are recognized by Drush using the file names prefixed with the alias name.

You could try `drush @local.local status --debug`

First `local` from `@local.local` is the comes from the file name `local.aliases.drushrc.php`, and the second is the key of the `$aliases` array from the file.

To see a list of all the aliases present on the system, you would use `drush sa`.

Comment: I am using drupal 8 with drush 8. drush @local.local status --debug gave me the same error. cd into /var/www/html/test/testme/amber/amber_school_dev, error is Could not find a site definition. drush sa within site root is none, self, default